# A step in the proof of Atiyah' s exercise 2.26

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $N$ be an $A$-module. The exercise want to prove

> $N $ is flat  iff  $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(A/\alpha,N)=0$ for all finitely generated ideals  $\alpha$ in $A$

From the hint ，I know $N $ is flat  iff  $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(M,N)=0$ for all finitely generated $A$-modules $M$. If $M$ is finitely generated, let $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ be a set of generators of $M$, and let $M_{i}$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by $x_{1},...,x_{i}$.

Then the book says by considering the module $M_{i}/M_{i-1}$ and using  exercise 2.25 (exercise 2.25 is: let $\;0\rightarrow N'\rightarrow N \rightarrow N''\rightarrow 0$ be a  ses and $N''$ flat, then $N$ is flat iff and only if $N'$ is flat. ), deduce that $N$ is flat if $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(M,N)=0$
for all $M$ generated by a single element.

My question is how to use the exercise 2.25 to deduce that condition. I can only get that if $\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(M,N)=0$
for all $M$ generated by a single element, then $M_{i-1}\otimes N\rightarrow M_{i}\otimes N$ is injective.

Hope this is not a silly question.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Use induction on the number of generators. From the short exact sequence
$$ 0\to M_{i-1}\to M_{i}\to M_{i}/M_{i-1} \to 0 $$
(note that $ M_{i}/M_{i-1} $ is a cyclic module),
you deduce the long exact sequence of Tors:
\begin{align} \DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}
\dotsm\to\Tor^R_1(M_{i-1},N)\to \Tor^R_1(M_{i},N)
&\to\underbrace{\Tor^R_1(M_{i}/M_{i-1},N)}_{ =\,0}\to\\[0.5ex]
\to M_{i-1}\otimes_R N\to M_{i}\otimes_R N&\to M_{i}/M_{i-1}\otimes_R N \to 0
\end{align}
and use the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Is the SES supposed to be $0 \rightarrow M_{i-1} \rightarrow M_i \rightarrow M_i / M_{i-1} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: the second exact sequence is incorrect. Should it be $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}
\Tor^R_1(M_{i-1},N)\to \Tor^R_1(M_{i},N) \to \Tor^R_1(M_{i}/M_{i-1},N) \to M_{i-1}\otimes_R N\to M_{i}\otimes_R N \to (M_{i}/M_{i-1})\otimes_R N$$

Comment: @AolongLi: You're perfectly right. I wonder why I reversed the arrows, except perhaps, for my excuse,  I had worked before on a long exact sequence of Exts and I was getting tired… Thanks for pointing it!